# Sum of powers of the sum of all the square numbers in a factorial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, factorial, exponential-sum

Here's the exact question:

The sum of all positive integers $p$ such that $13! \div p$ is a perfect square, can be written as $2^a . 3^b . 5^c . 7^d . 11^e . 13^f$ where $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ are positive integers. Find $(a + b + c + d + e + f)$

Can someone please help me how to start with this question?

Here is my approach:
I tried to factorise $13!$ as $2^{10} . 3^5 . 5^2 . 7^1 . 11^1 . 13^1$
Then I knew that $p$ must have factors of $2^{even} . 3^{odd} . 5^{even} . 7^1 . 11^1 . 13^1$
But now I cannot proceed further on thinking the sum of all such possible $p$'s.....

Any hint/suggestion will work! Also, anyone can also suggest formatting issues/edit the question without changing its actual meaning, thank you!!!

PS: I donot think this is a duplicate, I did not find similar questions to this....

Comment: Note:  as a general rule, people reserve $p$ for primes, but that's clearly not what you intend here.

Comment: To attack the problem, I'd start by noting that your divisor must be divisible by $7\times 11\times 13$ (why?).  that cuts down a lot of the options.

Comment: @lulu yes, i did till that much only

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  We can't know what you have done if you don't tell us, and we'll waste our time telling you things you already know.  In any case, having handled the large primes, the small ones are similar...$5^2$, for example, exactly divides $13!$ so your divisor must either be prime to $5$ or divisible by $5^2$.

Comment: @lulu i am sorry, i will add my steps right away, thanks for your hint though

Comment: If all else fails, it is fairly easy to do this by hand.  After all, you know much more than "the exponent of $5$ is even". It can only be $0$ or $2$, with similar restrictions for $2,3$.  There are only $36$ possible combinations of powers of $2,3,5$ to consider and you can greatly simplify the arithmetic if you want, or just do it by brute force.

Comment: @lulu umm okay, but if there could be any better solution than this? I am waiting for other responses too, thanks

Comment: A quick and easy computation should never be discarded...if nothing else, it lets you check whatever other method someone hands you.

Comment: As a way to streamline the computation, note that your divisor must be divisible by $3$ and what's left over is the square of a divisor of $2^{5}\times 3^2\times 5$.

Comment: @lulu, i donot think the divisor necessarily needs to be divisible by $3^2$, it can be $3^0$ as well....

Comment: I didn't say it needed to be divisible by $3^2$.  I said it had to be divisible by $3$.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to find sum of divisors of an integer via $ ( 1 + p + p^2 + ... ) ( 1 + q + q^2 + ...) ...$? If so, can you apply that idea here? You've already described what the values look like, which is most of the crux.

Comment: @CalvinLin oh no, i am not too familiar with this, but your solution helps! i guess we just take the common brackets directly without solving all of the 36 values of p, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has stated, with a slight correction, that

> $p$ must be of the form $2^{even} . 3^{odd} . 5^{even} . 7^1 . 11^1 . 13^1$

Let's clarify that further (and it's implied in the comments that OP knows this too):

> If $p = 2^a \times 3^b \times 5^c \times 7^d \times 11^e \times 13^f$, then
> $a \in \{ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 \}, b \in \{ 1, 3, 5 \}, c \in \{0, 2 \}, d = 1 , e = 1 , f = 1 $.
> Furthermore, this represents the complete classification of all such $p$.

How can we find the sum of all of these?
As lulu mentioned in the comments, we could just sum up the 36 values.
OP is asking in the comments if there is a more efficient method?

Hint: Find an expression such that in the expanded form, each of the terms correspond to a possible value of $p$.
Then, evaluate that expression.

> $(2^0 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^6 + 2^8 + 2^{10} ) \times ( 3^1 + 3^3 + 3^5) \times ( 5^0 + 5^2 ) \times 7 \times 11 \times 13$.

Note: This approach is very similar to finding the sum of divisors of an integer. Lulu mentioned that "your divisor must be divisible by 3 and what's left over is the square of a divisor of $ 2^5 \times 3^2 \times 5$", which explains the similarities.

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask you, what did you mean by "OP"? I am sorry, I have never heard of it.....and its off-topic too

Comment: OP = Original Poster (of the problem), which in this case is @CuckooBeats